# How to bind $_FILES to a Phalcon Form?

Tags: php, forms, validation, file-upload, phalcon

I have this part of code:

```
if ($this->request->isPost() && $this->request->hasFiles()) {
    $post = $this->request->getPost();
    $file = $this->request->getUploadedFiles();
    if ($form->isValid($post)) {
        $form->bind((array) $this->request->getPost(), $entity);
        $entity->save();

        // Do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pass `$file` to a Phalcon\Forms\Form object? 
Or another practice to check if validity of a form that contains both files and text?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no built in method in Phalcon to validate a file upload via a form. You need to write some custom code for this. Try checking out this link https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/3583/how-to-validate-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

To validate Files you must use the FileValidator Class as this example:

```
$file = new FileValidator([
        'maxSize' => '10M',
        'messageSize' => _('Your file is huge. Max allowed is 10 Mb'),
        'allowedTypes' => ["image/jpeg", "image/png"],
        'messageType' => _('File type is not permitted. Try with JPG, GIF, etc..'),
        'messageEmpty' => _('Cannot be empty. Please upload a file')
]);

$this->validator->add('filesInputName', $file);
$messages = $this->validator->validate($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but as it affects my current project I share my solution.
Normally, I'm using form classes and validation classes, too. For validating a file upload along with other `POST` data, I simply combine both payloads:

```
$entity = new MyCustomModel();
$merged = array_merge($_POST, $_FILES);
if ($form->isValid($merged, $entity)) {
    // ...
}
```